# Can someone point me in the direction of why $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{T-1}A(1+R)^n = A\frac{(1+R)^T-1}{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Before you ask, this isn't a homework question, I am just curious.

I was trying to derive an expression for compound interest with evenly spaced deposits.

I reached the point: $F = I(1+R)^T + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{T-1}A(1+R)^n$

I = Initial deposit

A = Annual deposit

R = Interest rate

T = Period

Obviously this isn't the most easy expression to work with so I looked up the correct answer which is apparently:

$F = I(1+R)^T + A\frac{(1+R)^T-1}{R}$

Apparently these expression are equivalent, so my question is, how do I get from:

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{T-1}A(1+R)^n$ to $A\frac{(1+R)^T-1}{R}$?

Comment: This is a geometric series, [here's a link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) that explains the basic idea of how to arrive at the formula.

Comment: @pjs36 Ah that helped a bunch, I understand now thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this is a standard geometric series summation. let the first term be $a$ and the factor of increase be $x$. suppose there are $n-1$ increases, then:
$$
S = a + ax + ax^2 + \cdots + ax^{n-1}
$$
multiply by $x$
$$
Sx = ax + ax^2 + ax^3 + \cdots + ax^n
$$
subtract the first from the second:
$$
S(x-1) = ax^n -a
$$
this is the trick! all terms cancel except the two extremes.

simplifying:
$$
S = a\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}
$$
since in your case we have
$$
x=1+R \\
T=n
$$
the formula becomes:
$$
S= A\frac{(1+R)^T-1}{R}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your function is basically in the form of a geometric series, which we can write as
$$ S = \sum_{n=0}^{N} ar^n $$
for *first term* $a$ and *common ratio* $r$. The easiest way to see how to compute the sum is to write it out longhand, multiply it by $r$, and then subtract:
$$ \begin{align*}
S &= a + ar + ar^2 + \dotsb + ar^n \\
rS &= \phantom{a+{}} ar+ ar^2 + \dotsb + ar^n + ar^{n+1} \\
(r-1)S &= -a + ar^{n+1} \\
S &= a\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}
\end{align*}$$